# In R/factoextra, a question about 'fviz_cluster'

Tags: r

In R,  when using 'fviz_cluster' ,
the plot show axis.x 'Dim1' /axis.y 'Dim2' , but these can't find in 'km.res' ( the 'kmeans' result).
Anyone can help to explain ? thanks

```
library(factoextra)
data("iris")
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[,-5])
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled,3,nstart=10)

fviz_cluster(km.res,iris[,-5],
             ellipse.type = "norm",
             palette='Set2',
             ggtheme=theme_minimal())
```

[image]

Comment: You should be able to re-calculate the components using something like: `princomp(iris.scaled,  cor = TRUE)$scores[,1:2]`

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  I am not want "Principal Component Analysis".      I'm just confused that  'kmeans' result not include 'Dim1/Dim2', but the plot include 'Dim1/Dim2'.

Comment: But Dim1/Dim2 **are** the principal components.... Best of luck